# Can Elasticsearch Java client be updated in run-time?

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch

I am working with an Elasticsearch `RestHighLevelClient` bean initialized by Spring when my app starts. Now I want to give users the ability to change the connection to Elasticsearch in run-time.

I wonder if there is any *elegant* way to update a connection to Elasticsearch nodes from a Java client (either the Low Level or the High Level). And by *elegant* I mean without having to reopen the client for every operation, nor with a flag to inform there was an update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define several ES client beans in your Spring config and qualify (e.g. `@Qualifier("one")`) them. Then at runtime you can lookup manually the best client by using `ApplicationContext#getBean()` methods

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that Elasticsearch would have such a possibility.

The solution you are looking for could be `Connection Pool`. As you mentioned you want to avoid reopening connection for every operation, `Connection Pool` allows you keeping a few open connections. This is a common pattern for managing many database connections.